# Can't disable user signup in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I'm using Grafana v2.6.0 on a Centos server. In /etc/grafana/grafana.ini, I set allow sign_up to false:

```
[users]
;allow_sign_up = false
```

Then I restarted grafana-server.

When I go to the login page, the signup tab is still visible, and when I look at settings in the grafan app, allow_sign_up is still true.   How do I disable signup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that both "#" and ";" are used for comments in the grafana.ini file. To make a change take effect, you must uncomment the setting by removing the ";" from the front of the line, like this:

```
[users]
allow_sign_up = false
```